# Can one construct the Gell-Mann matrices from Pauli matrices?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, mp.mathematical-physics

I'm essentially interested in understanding the connection between SU(2) and SU(3). I would be particularly interested in connections between the Pauli matrices and the Gell-Mann matrices.

I've read that there are 3 independent SU(2) subalgebras that one can form from the Gell-Mann matrices but I am interested in going the other way and constructing the Gell-Mann matrices from the Paulis. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by "constructing" a 3x3 matrix from a 2x2 matrix; am I allowed to take the direct sum with a scalar? The Gell-Mann matrices have Pauli matrices "inside"...

Comment: The Lie algebra of the group $SU(N)$ consists of traceless anti-hermitian matrices. It is easy to compute its real dimension: N-1 degrees from the diagonal and 2N degrees from each element above the diagonal (for N=3 this gives 8). This is a vector space and the Gell-Mann matrices are a particular basis for it when N=3. This construction is very simple and works for any value $N$, so I don't think there is much sense in trying to "get" the N=3 case "from" the N=2 case, somehow.

Comment: By constructing I mean a mapping that sends one from the fundametal representation of SU(2) to irreps of SU(3). The sense in going to the N=3 to the N=2 case is that while the fundamental irrep of SU(2) is a 2X2 matrix the N irrep is constructable as the symmetic subspace of N copies of the fundamental irrep and is an NXN space. It would seem then that it's not quite enough to say that as the groups are based on matrices of a certain size that their irreps are incompatible particularly  when we recall that the Paulis and Gell-Mann matrices can be seen as merely irreps.